# Glassfish: sun-web.xml missing

Tags: java, xml, glassfish-3, netbeans-7

I'm currently trying to set up a secured folder with a few pages within my Java Web App to allow only registered users to access the pages in that folder.

However, while trying to do the setup/mapping of the groups I have been having the issue that the sun-web.xml is missing. I'm using Netbeans IDE.

Any ideas why this happened and how to fix it? I've done research and haven't really found a solution for the issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a file named glassfish-web.xml?

Comment: @BheshGurung thanks for the response. There is no GlassFish-web.xml either. Is there a way that you can this file manually? like when I add an web.xml?

Comment: Try: right-click the project > New > Other, then form the Categories select Glassfish. After that from Files, select glassfish-web.xml.

Comment: @BheshGurung -- Tried that but the possibility to glassfish-web.xml was not shown. I however manage to get the file by updating Netbeans to 7.2. I can use this file instead of the sun-web.xml, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem fixed: I updated Netbeans to 7.2 from 7.0 and then I did what @Bhesh Gurung suggested:

> Try: right-click the project > New > Other, then form the Categories select Glassfish. After that from Files, select glassfish-web.xmlBlockquote

Comment: I'm using netbeans 7.2 and on my end it's called GlassFish Descripter in the new dialog.